# SSMS v18.9.2 Display Estimated Execution Plan returning XML error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

From SSMS v18.9.2, when highlight a simple Select query like `select * from sys.tables`" in the master database (or any database), I get the following message:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Error processing execution plan results. The error message is:
> There is an error in XML document (1, 2049).
> Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 2049.

Anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the issue was my `SET TEXTSIZE` option was set to 0.  I changed it to 2147483647 and the issue went away.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> General.  Then, in the SET TEXTSIZE box, enter 2147483647, and click OK.